# What is the maximum value for maxDistance for Apple Wallet Pass

Tags: ios, wallet

As per the Apple Developer Guide, ***maxDistance*** = "Maximum distance in meters from a relevant latitude and longitude that the pass is relevant. This number is compared to the pass’s default distance and the smaller value is used."

So we can set **maxDistance** value for any Apple Wallet Pass, but they haven't mention that ***what will be the maximum number*** that we can pass as the maxDistance.

Also what does it means ***pass’s default distance*** ?

Also sometime the Location alert comes and sometime it won't. Is that a bug in wallet feature ?

Comment: It seems that there is no maximum value for maxDistance

Comment: @Masiama, Thanks for the update. But in that case i can set up to 10 km radius as maxDistance ? Also why sometimes Location alert is not coming although i am on the same location ?

Comment: I think Apple hope for the common sense of the developer, so distance should be within reason

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have set maxDistance of 5000 meter, although it is giving location alert only for the near by location like near by 500-1000 meters and not for 5000 meter.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wallet Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html) radius depends on the pass style.

> When the location is interpreted with a small radius, the current location must be on the order of a hundred meters or closer; with a large radius, on the order of a thousand meters or closer.

Large radius (max. 1000m):

- Event ticket
- Boarding pass

Small radius (max. 100m):

- Coupon
- Store card
- Generic

But you have to be aware that these values can change.

> In both cases, the exact relevance radius is an implementation detail and may change.

Moreover, you won't get a notification every time.

> Boarding passes and event tickets almost always specify a relevant date, so they appear only on the valid date, and not each time the user is near the location.